# is the eternal return of material violence etc.?

Tags: reference-request, nietzsche, nihilism, deleuze

Does anyone claim that what Nietzsche's heroes (and antiheroes?) will the return of isn't every violent human (or natural?) mistake, but some particular aspect of history?

Comment: Any chance you could unpack this a bit further? What exactly are you hoping for someone to explain to you here?

Comment: i have no idea why it isn't clear, so clarifying will be difficult. is there anything in particular you don't understand or can't read ?

Comment: I believe what Joseph is saying is that your question is grammatically incorrect which of course causes confusion.

Comment: can you say where it is grammatically correct e.g @megachuck

Comment: This needn't be an answer, but in response to your question-I think the answer must be no.  I think it would be inappropriate to interpret Nietzsche's meaning that way.  It is not that we wish to repeat certain things - it is that if we are condemned to repeat all of it - are we living in such a way as to experience that repetition as a blessing or a curse?  It is meant to draw attention to ourselves and the way we live.

Comment: Also, I think it is easy to think read this question as grammatically incorrect like @megachuck did. It isn't, but it feels clunky because of the parenthesis, and the fact that our brains don't want parse the word `will` with the meaning that you intend it to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems clear in context that what one is meant to be wishing for when wishing for eternal recurrence is the repetition of *this moment now*. The point is to always live in such a way that you would not want any alternative version of the current moment more than the one that is already happening, if you could back off and consider it in context for arbitrarily long, because this moment can be expected to lead into to moments you would wish never to lose.

E.g. one appearance is:

> What, if some day or night a demon were to steal after you into your loneliest loneliness and say to you: 'This life as you now live it and have lived it, you will have to live once more and innumerable times more' ... Would you not throw yourself down and gnash your teeth and curse the demon who spoke thus? Or have you once experienced a tremendous moment when you would have answered him: 'You are a god and never have I heard anything more divine.' (The Gay Science)

The moments (in this case the ultimate single moment) you would wish to have return forever should offset every moment you might wish had turned out differently.  Whatever others must suffer for you to regain those peaks is both largely irrelevant, and completely outside your power to control.

Comment: It says "as you now live it and have lived it."  That does not just mean "as you now live it."  It includes "as you ... have lived it."

Comment: @ColinMcLarty But you are being told by the 'demon' that you are in an eternal recurrence, which means there is about zero percent chance that this is the first time.  So of course you have previously lived it exactly this way as well as living it now.  (What does that have to do with the answer, in any way?)

Comment: i'm in fact going to go with this as a v sophisticated and perhaps correct answer, thanks